# Solving $2(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)=(m-3)(m+3)$

Tags: diophantine-equations, factoring, integers

The question is:

> Find all pairs $(n,m)\in\mathbb{N}^2$ such that
>   $$2(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)=(m-3)(m+3)$$

I checked all $n<10000$ and only got $n=1$ and $n=4$ with their corresponding $m$, so I suspect those are the only solutions. I tried using quadratic residues, or the fact that the expression is factored, but no luck. I even tried solving for $n$, and using the fact that that has to be an integer, but that led to $$((2n+1)^2-5)^2=8N^2-56$$ which wasn't that useful either. Can anyone help me out here? Thanks!

Comment: have you ever heard of Pell equation? If $a = n^2 + n - 1$, then $m^2 - 2a^2 = 7$, this equation has solution $(3, 1), (5, 3), (13, 9), (27, 19), (75, 53) ...$ and it is going to have infinite many solutions using a formula. Then maybe you can show only some of them can be in form of $a = n^2 + n - 1$.

Comment: I thought of that too, however, the closed form of that is not easy to work with, and thus finding those numbers of the form $n^2+n-1$ is quite hard

Comment: it is quite easy to get closed form actually... $a = \frac{1}{4}((2-3\sqrt{2})(3-2\sqrt{2})^n + (2 + 3\sqrt{2})(3 + 2\sqrt{2})^n)$ or $a = \frac{1}{4}((-2-3\sqrt{2})(3-2\sqrt{2})^n + (3\sqrt{2} - 2)(3 + 2\sqrt{2})^n)$

Comment: I wasn't referring to *getting* the closed form being hard, I tried to say that the closed form is hard to work with. Looking at that, I would have no idea how to say when it is or isn't of the form $n^2+n-1$

Comment: I considered mod 5. If $5|(n-2)$, the LHS is congruent to $24$ and the right hand side is congruent to $m^2-9$, so you get $m^2=3 \mod 5$, which is not possible. Hence one of the factors on the LHS is divisible by $5$ so you get $m=5k+3$ or $m=5k+2$. It is also easy to see that $3$ divides $m$, so you get $m=15k+3$ or $m=15k-3$. Furthermore, $8$ must divide both sides of the equation so $m$ must be odd and hence $m=30k \pm 3$. Could this be useful?

Comment: If n=4, the left side is 2x3x4x5x6 = 120 and this is not $m^2-9$ for any m. I think I have a solution, which I will now post.

Comment: marty cohen No, you get $720$ not $120$, so $m^2 = 729 = 27 ^2$

Comment: I have an idea, the expressionis not that bad, you can get one of the two part abandoned since that is almost 0 when n gets large. The other part you can take square root easily, but it will be hard to after taking integer part.

Comment: @Yimin, interesting, but we don't only need to take the square root, we need to solve $n^2+n-1=$ *expression with roots*

Comment: Oops. My mistake.

Comment: @vrugtehagel You could repeat the same procedure for $\mod 7$, to find that $7|(n-4)$, $7|(n-3)$ and $7|(n-2)$ are not possible, so you must have $7|(m-3)(m+3)$. You will find that $m=120k \pm 3$ or $m=210k + 30 \pm3$.

Comment: Solving that seems not needed, I guess we just need to show that there is no integers between sqrt(4a+4) and sqrt(4a+6). In other word, they have same integer parts.

Answer (score 1):

The nonnegative integer solutions of the Pell equation are $\pmatrix{m\cr a\cr} = M^k \pmatrix{3\cr 1\cr}$ and $M^k \pmatrix{5\cr 3\cr}$ for $k \ge 0$, where $M = \pmatrix{3 & 4\cr 2 & 3\cr}$.
In order for $a = n^2 + n - 1$, we need $5+4a$ to be a square.  It appears that the only cases where this is true are $M^0 \pmatrix{3\cr 1\cr} = \pmatrix{
3\cr 1\cr}$, corresponding to the solution $(m=3,n=1)$, and 
$M^1 \pmatrix{5\cr 3\cr} = \pmatrix{27\cr 19\cr}$, corresponding to $(m= 27, n= 4)$.  There are no other solutions for $k \le 10000$ (corresponding to $n \le  1.03 \times 10^{3828})$.
However, I don't have a proof that these are all the solutions.

I might note that your equation is an elliptic curve, with Weierstrass form
$s^3- \dfrac{268}{3} s-\dfrac{7040}{27}+t^2 = 0$ according to Maple.  An expert in elliptic curves (not I) might be able to prove that there are only the two positive integer solutions.